# argpartition is exhibiting unexpected behavior

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to use argpartition from numpy. In particular, I am trying to understand the following behavior.

```
arr = [4,5,2,1,9,7]
np.argpartition(np.array(arr), 1)
```

The output I get is:

```
array([3, 2, 1, 0, 4, 5])
```

but I expected instead:

```
array([3, 2, 0, 1, 4, 5])
```

since 5 is larger than 4

What am I missing here? I'm having the same issue when I change the second parameter of argpartition to 0 (1 comes before 0, although I expected the opposite)

Comment: `argpartition` doesn't guarantee the order of elements within partitions

Answer (score 0):

If you want a complete sort, call argsort. You asked for a partition, and you got it.

There are no order guarantees within each side of the partition. The only guarantee is that elements smaller than the partition point go before the partition point, and elements higher than the partition point go after.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is exactly what you're looking for, although the output doesn't match the one you expected. However I think it's just that you miscalculated the desired output:

```
import numpy as np
arr = [4,5,2,1,9,7] 
print(np.argsort(np.array(arr), 0))
>>>output([3 2 0 1 5 4])
```

Hope this helps.